# How to add drawingView in maui project

Tags: maui, .net-maui, maui-community-toolkit, maui-compat

How to add DrawingView or Signaturepad in Maui using CommunityToolkit.maui.core, or how can I implement Signaturepad in maui project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both aren't supported for .NET MAUI right now.

For the Release Candidate of the Community Toolkit we plan to have DrawingView, the PR is mostly ready. However, for Windows it will be unsupported, simply because WinUI hasn't implemented the necessary bits yet.